# How was the Triangle Inequality applied in this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity, triangle-inequality

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $E ⊂ X$ be a nonempty subset. Define a function

$f : X → [0, ∞)$ by: $$f(x):= \inf \{d(x,y):y \in E \}$$

Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $ X$ .

Let me share a very short solution that is confirmed by my instructor, but which I don't understand how the Triangle Inequality was applied.

Solution:

Let $\delta=\frac {\epsilon}{2}$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Let arbitrary points $x_1, x_2$ satisfy $d(x_1,x_2)< \delta$.

Then, $f(x_1) <f(x_2)+2 \delta$ and $f(x_2)<f(x_1)+ 2\delta$.

Thus, $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<2\delta=\epsilon$.

Hence it is uniformly continuous on $X$.

The instructor said, "$f(x_1) <f(x_2)+2 \delta$ and $f(x_2)<f(x_1)+ 2\delta$" could be found using the Triangle Inequality, but I wonder how. Can I get some enlightenment here?

Comment: Prove that $f(x)-f(y) \leq d(x,y)$ (and $f(y)-f(x) \leq d(x,y)$).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think OP meant $\delta$ in place of $2\delta$. Check my answer? There's no way to get $2\delta$ (same as your comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $x_1,x_2$ satisfy $d(x_1,x_2) < \delta$. Also, $$f(x_1):= \inf \{d(x_1,y):y \in E\}$$
$$f(x_2):= \inf \{d(x_2,y):y \in E\}$$
By the triangle inequality, $$d(x_1,y) \le d(x_1,x_2) + d(x_2,y)$$ for every $y$.
Also, $$\inf\{d(x_1,y): y\in E\} \le d(x_1,y)$$
so,
$$\inf\{d(x_1,y): y\in E\} \le d(x_1,x_2) + d(x_2,y)$$ for every $y$. Now the LHS is independent of $y$, and the inequality holds for all $y$. Taking the infimum over $y\in E$ we get
$$\inf\{d(x_1,y): y\in E\} \le d(x_1,x_2) + \inf\{d(x_2,y): y\in E\}$$
but this is just
$$f(x_1) \le d(x_1,x_2) + f(x_2)$$
and $d(x_1,x_2) < \delta$ quickly gives
$$f(x_1) \le f(x_2) + \delta$$
You can just swap $x_1$ and $x_2$, repeat the entire procedure above to get
$$f(x_2) \le f(x_1) + \delta$$
I hope this provides the necessary enlightenment.